IRS online account missing one year of my account transcripts
I am very intrigued why the IRS doesn't show year 2016 of my account transcripts. Is it an error or intentional? How do I go about requesting it online?
These transcripts show changes you or the IRS made after the original return was filed, such as making estimated tax payments or filing an amended return.
Pls see the image below.


Mine only goes back to 2018. Of course 2020 and earlier, if timely filed, are no longer open to assessment, and not to refund unless there was a new payment (well) after filing; in the old system these would be archived from IMF, and I don't know if or how CADE2 changes this. Before 2014 is uncollectible unless there has been an extension e.g. due to appeals office or tax court. And I didn't notice before the wording 'estimated payments' which makes no sense here; the paper version, f4506t, says 'payments made on the account, penalty assessments, and adjustments'

"These transcripts show changes you or the IRS made." -- perhaps they were simply no changes that year?  You should be retaining your own copies of tax forms for at least 7 years, plus is much longer as you think you will want to refer back to them.
